# How to monitor ADSL2+ modem

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router, adsl2+

I have thomson TG58547 ADSL2+ router to provide WiFy internet brodband, My router is working fine if its connected to only one device through WiFy but when I connect mobile to access WiFi it starts behaving weirdly. I have observed following behavior

1) Some time both mobile and laptop can successfully be connected to WiFi and can access internet

2) Some times if I am using WiFi on mobile and try to connect laptop router get disturbed and do not allow laptop to connect to WiFi but after restarting router everything works fine

3) sometimes restarting router don't solve this problem, then I have to turn off my mobile WiFi and laptop WiFi switch and after restarting router and then turning on both devices WiFi work again

So I want to know why exactly this kind of problem arises and how it can be avoided, Secondly is there any utility software available to monitor routers status and control its behavior like refreshing it or something to avoid switch off - switch on permutation & combination.

Comment: update your question to include the 802.11 mode and frequency used.

Comment: I dont knoe about frequency and 802.11 mode... how do I find it?

Comment: Lets start with which modes does the ADSL gateway support